# Sqlite DB File is too huge....?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, filesize

I've been creating a dictionary file that contains 85000 records with Sqlite and QT. the file of sqlite is too huge, it's 134MB, and another dictionary like MDic DB have same data that created with sqlite and same records is 10 MB!

```
query.exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY");
query.exec("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");

Dic_entry DictionaryEntry = DictionaryInstance.readEntry();

QString definition, headword, displayedHeadWord;
query.exec("BEGIN Transaction");
int Count = 0;
while(!DictionaryEntry.headword.empty())
{
    definition = QString::fromStdString(DictionaryEntry.definition);
    definition.replace("'", "''");

    headword = QString::fromStdString(DictionaryEntry.headword);
    headword.replace("'", "''");

    displayedHeadWord = QString::fromStdString(DictionaryEntry.displayedHeadword);
    displayedHeadWord.replace("'", "''");

    string strQuery = "INSERT INTO Dictionary_Words([Definition], [HeadWord], [DisplayedHeadWord]) "
        "values('"
        + definition.toStdString() + "', '"
        + headword.toStdString() + "', '"
        + displayedHeadWord.toStdString()
        + "')";

    query.exec(QString::fromStdString(strQuery));
    if(Count == 200)
    {
        query.exec("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
        Count = 0;
    }
    Count++;

    DictionaryEntry = DictionaryInstance.readEntry();
}

query.exec("End Transaction");
query.exec("CREATE INDEX HW_idx ON [Dictionary_Words](HeadWord)");
query.exec("CREATE INDEX Def_idx ON [Dictionary_Words](Definition)");
query.exec("CREATE INDEX DHW_idx ON [Dictionary_Words](DisplayedHeadword)");
query.exec("PRAGMA auto_vacuum=FULL");
db.close();
```

Please help me that how can i reduce my SQlite DB file

Comment: Why is your code half-way across my screen?!

Comment: This is admittedly off-topic, but SQLite has a data binding API that allows you to apply data without having to constantly create "INSERT INTO" statements and execute them in a loop. It also means that you don't have to sanitize your inputs; since the strings bound to those parameters cannot interfere with the SQL statement's logic. You should look into doing this; it saves a lot of time and effort (though it has nothing to do with the eventual file size).

Comment: I've used SQLite in the past, and I've never seen it take up that much space. My music database contains 6000+ songs, and it only takes up 20MB or so. And that has multiple tables of various artist data and such, along with triggers, common views, etc. Are you certain that the code you're showing is the _only_ data stored in the DB?

Comment: Just a side note, if you use the Qt features better then you can write much clearer code. For example: `QString strQuery = QString("INSERT INTO Dictionary_Words([Definition], [HeadWord], [DisplayedHeadWord]) values('%1','%2','%3')").arg(definition, headword, displayedHeadWord);` to construct your query.

Answer (score 0):

I have no way of proving it, but I suspect the indexes are the cause of the trouble. Indexes can take up a huge amount of space, and you've got three of them. Try it without them and see if the access is still acceptably fast; the database size should be much smaller that way.